# Prevent selected items in unfocused table widget from becoming gray

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

When I select items in `QTableWidget`, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I focus other widget, it looks like this:

[image]

I want the items to remain blue as long as they're selected. I tried to enforce it using QSS (CSS):

```
QListWidget::item:selected:active, QListWidget::item:selected:!active {
    background: blue;
}

QListWidget::item:selected {
    background: blue;
}
```

Didn't help. What can I do to prevent selected items from becoming gray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `background:` is not the correct property to change selection background. This is correct:

```
QTableView::item:selected:!active
{
       /*selection-background-color: #3399ff;*/
    selection-background-color: #93CAFF;
    /** doesnt work **/
    color: white;
}
```

The text color setting still doesn't work, but it's better than nothing.

[image]

Comment: `selection-color` should exist too. Another solution could be to set the color of the palette (`QPalette::setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Foreground, currentPalette->color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Foreground)`)

Comment: QPalette::Highlight and QPalette::HighlightText rather presumably.